# Fuse failing to make contact

Tags: electrical, bmw, fuse

[image: FuseBox]Good afternoon all

The sports exhaust valves have recently been failing on my 2016 BMW M2, upon further investigation, I've found that the bluetooth unit that speaks with the remote control for the exhaust valves has not been powering on.

Examining the fusebox, I've found that when you apply pressure to the top of the fuse responsible, the unit powers on and the valves start responding, but goes off again as soon as you release the pressure.

Is there anyway to repair this, or is it likely a damaged contact within the fusebox itself,  so a replacement box will be required?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of fuse? What kind of fusebox? A picture of both would be useful; you can add an image to the question using the "Edit" button below the text, followed by selecting the "Moon and Mountains" button that appears above the text composition box.

Comment: Substitute a same-rating fuse from another circuit. If the problem disappears, the problem is in the original fuse, which should be replaced. If the problem continues, the problem is in the fuse socket or wiring to the fuse socket.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have now attached a picture of the fusebox, the fuse in question is the Blue 15 third one down on the left. If I use my finger and apply pressure on top of the fuse, the exhaust valves system powers on, but turns off as soon as I release.

Comment: have replaced the fuse with another, same outcome. Thanks

Comment: Did you solve this problem? If not then you may have to remove the fuse panel (disconnect battery negative first, reconnect last) and examine those two fuse terminals and wiring for damage. This isn't a friendly diy repair but can be if patient and know your way around wiring. Tugging each wire crimped onto the fuse terminal may reveal whether or not corrosion occurred.